# Google Chrome "This webpage is not available" error on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome

I'm using Snow Leopard and I've just downloaded Google Chrome for Mac. However it doesn't load any page:

This webpage is not available.

```
Error 104 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED): The attempt to connect to the server failed.
```

I've googled about it but I had no luck, only answers for Windows. Needless to say I have no firewalls and every other browser or application can connect to the internet.

Comment: In Console.app, are there any relevant messages for Chrome when this happens?

Comment: It doesn't happen at home, only at work. I guess it's some firewall configuration? It's still weird that every program can access the internet except this one.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a firewall issue.

Are you using Zone Alarm or something similar that has been misconfigured to block Chrome?